# remapping whole namespace in launchfile

Tags: ros, roslaunch, namespace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's say I have a node with several topics like this:

```
/group/node/topic1
/group/node/topic2
/group/node/topic3
...
```

Now I want to remap all topics to a different namespace like this:

```
/important_topics/topic1
/important_topics/topic2
/important_topics/topic2
...
```

Is there an easy way to do this in a launchfile without remapping every single topic? For example something like this:

```
<remap from="/group/node/" to="/important_topics/" />
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231051/remapping-whole-namespace-in-launchfile/) by [JohnDoe2991](https://answers.ros.org/users/21163/johndoe2991/) on ROS Answers with karma: 305 on 2016-04-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think this is yet possible. See [Here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/209).

---

Originally posted by [vschmidt](https://answers.ros.org/users/25950/vschmidt/) with karma: 242 on 2016-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2